# Django 1.8 KeyError: 'manager' on relationship

Tags: django

I have models set up like this:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post,related_name='comments')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

And when I want to get all the comments from a post `somepost.comments()` I get the following error:

```
>> somepost.comments()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "a_path/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 693, in __call__
    manager = getattr(self.model, kwargs.pop('manager'))
KeyError: 'manager'
```

Comment: this tripped me up for an embarrassingly long time.   although partly because tab-completion gives you `somepost.comments(`

Comment: I also posted this because google turns up nothing useful for the cryptic `KeyError: 'manager'`

Comment: Also got this error when I thought this was the right way to get the groups of a user, is `user_object.groups()`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It should be `somepost.comments.all()`.

`somepost.comments` returns a queryset.  `all` accesses the objects in it.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `somepost.comment_set.all()` 
`_set` is used for reverse mapping in `django models`.

Comment: Partially incorrect in this context. When you use `related_name` on the `ForeignKey()` this will be used *instead of* `<originating model name>_set`. Thus, in this case it's only `somepost.comments`, not `somepost.comments_set`.

Comment: thats true but if related_name is not defined or otherwise also _set method can be used.