# Django, 'KeyError' while spanning relationships

Tags: python, django

I've been searching through the internet for a while, but couldn't get a solution to that error.
The closest problem to mine that I found on stackoverflow is:
[Django 1.8 KeyError: 'manager' on relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32889243/django-1-8-keyerror-manager-on-relationship) but In my opinion I am calling `filter()` correctly. **What is causing that error?**

Here is how I call the function:

```
class DummySearchStrategy(GoalPartnersSearchStrategy):
def find(self, location, goal):
    return Person.objects.filter(person_skill__skill__in = goal.relevantSkills, locationname = location)
```

PersonSkill has a `ForeignKey` to Person (with `related_name='person_skill'`, as well as `ForeignKey` to Skill

And here is the traceback

```
Traceback:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  58.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in dispatch
  466.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in dispatch
  463.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\kazimiera\PycharmProjects\coflow_site5\restserver\src\apps\prototype\views\dictionaries.py" in get
  338.         serializer = PersonGetSerializer(partners_generator.search(person, goal))
File "C:\Users\kazimiera\PycharmProjects\coflow_site5\restserver\src\apps\prototype\businesslogic\candidatelist\algorithms\partners_search.py" in search
  19.         self.how_to.find(localization, goal)
File "C:\Users\kazimiera\PycharmProjects\coflow_site5\restserver\src\apps\prototype\businesslogic\candidatelist\algorithms\partners_search.py" in find
  12.         return Person.objects.filter(person_skill__skill__in = goal.relevantSkills, locationname = location)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in manager_method
  127.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in filter
  679.         return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _filter_or_exclude
  697.             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in add_q
  1310.         clause, require_inner = self._add_q(where_part, self.used_aliases)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in _add_q
  1338.                     allow_joins=allow_joins, split_subq=split_subq,
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in build_filter
  1156.         value, lookups, used_joins = self.prepare_lookup_value(value, lookups, can_reuse, allow_joins)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in prepare_lookup_value
  1003.             value = value()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py" in __call__
  882.             manager = getattr(self.model, kwargs.pop('manager'))

Exception Type: KeyError at /api/people/1/goals/1/candidates
Exception Value: u'manager'
```

Comment: Can you post your person model?

Comment: And whatever `goal` is. If `relevantSkills` is also a relationship, then the linked question has the exact answer.

Comment: Provide more details about your models. `related_name` are not used to search fields, it's used for reverse relation to get the list of skills of the Person: `Person.person_skill.all()`, and conventionally its should be plural (person_skills).

Comment: show your models, it sounds like you really have a many-to-many relation through the `PersonSkill` model

Comment: @DanielRoseman that was exactly the case! I changed it to 'goal.relevantSkills.all()' and it seems to work now. Thank you all guys! :)